# Can one generalize $x^TAx \leq \lambda x^Tx$ for distinct vectors like $x^TAy \leq \lambda x^Ty$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Say a spd. matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ has maximum eigenvalue $\lambda_{ \max}$. I know that it is true that
$$ x^TA x \leq \lambda_{ \max} x^Tx$$ for every vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, but is this true for two vector $x$ and $y$? Like, can I say that
$$ x^TAy \leq |\lambda_{ \max}|x^Ty?$$
Or if not so can I say that $x^TAy \leq cx^Ty$ for some constant $c$ involving the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: Obviously not! Change $y$ to $-y$ to see why such an inequality cannot hold.

Comment: Your last question IS OBVIOUSLY TRUE by considering $c = 1;$ in fact, it will always be true regardless of $A.$

Comment: Whe such a quesiton first comes to your mind consider the case $n=1$ first.

Comment: Oops. I meant $x^TAy \leq cx^Ty$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &1 \\ 0 &0 \end{bmatrix}.$ Then $\lambda_\max = 1$ attained at $(1, 0)^\intercal.$ However, $(2, 1) A (1, 1)^\intercal = 4$ and $(2, 1) (1, 1)^\intercal = 3$ which makes the desired inequality unattained. The most likely scenario is that what you want will never be true except rare circumstances.